# Using WHERE clause with BETWEEN and null date parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my `WHERE` clauses is the following:

```
AND (DateCreated BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo OR (@DateFrom IS NULL OR @DateTo IS NULL))
```

`@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` are input parameters that may be `NULL`.

If they are both null, then I need to basically ignore the `BETWEEN` and return all records.

If `@DateFrom` is `NULL`, but `@DateTo` is `NOT NULL`, then I need to return all records with DateCreated being no greater than `@DateTo` (inclusive).

If `@DateFrom` is `NOT NULL`, but `@DateTo` is `NULL`, then I need to return all records with DateCreated being no earlier than `@DateFrom` (inclusive) up to today's date.

DateCreated is not a null or some time it is null field.

So far my `WHERE` clause is not working exactly like I want.

Comment: Assuming both the column and parameters are `DATE`, then `WHERE DateCreated >= COALESCE(@DateTo, '19000101') AND DateCreated <= COALESCE(@DateFrom, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));` - if either of them are `DATETIME`, you need to stop thinking about "between"...

Comment: I think it would be worth reading [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). Although not incorrect I agree with the article in that `BETWEEN` causes more problems with ambiguity than it solves by shortening a predicate slightly.

Comment: @gvee no: `DateCreated is not a null field.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that course would defeat any indexes, resulting in a full table read.

Comment: @Matt I disagree 100%. If the parameters are not null, and there is a usable index on DateCreated, it will be used. I define "usable" there loosely - needs to cover the query or not introduce lookups that are too costly. But the predicate I wrote is definitely sargable. If your parameters are NULL you're probably doing a full scan anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the COALESCE and CONVERT calculations would occur on every row being assessed.

Comment: @Matt Please read the code a little more carefully. Those are happening against the parameters, not against the column. Any proper RDBMS would know to only perform that operation once.

Comment: @Matt - this would be true if a column value was contained inside the `COALESCE` or `CONVERT` functions. The code is just `COALESCE(@DateFrom, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))` - Both the parameter `@DateFrom` and the system function `GETDATE()` are runtime constants, therefore `COALESCE` and `CONVERT` will only be evaluated once.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have tested and I concede.

Comment: Do you have an index on `CreatedDate`? If so you will probably benefit by breaking your query up with `IF/ELSE` and having 4 different where clause to cover the combinations, **or** using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` [query hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) to ensure an appropriate plan is chosen.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you should post your comment as a response. So far, it's the only one that doesn't override the index.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just need some extra criteria to handle when one or the other is `NULL`:

```
AND (
    (DateCreated >= @DateFrom and DateCreated < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)) 
 OR (@DateFrom IS NULL AND @DateTo IS NULL)
 OR (@DateFrom IS NULL AND DateCreated < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo))
 OR (@DateTo IS NULL AND DateCreated >= @DateFrom)
    )
```

Edit: Giorgi's approach was simpler, here it is adapted for use with `DATETIME`:

```
AND (       (DateCreated >= @DateFrom OR @DateFrom IS NULL) 
        AND (DateCreated < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo) OR @DateTo IS NULL)
    )
```

The issue with `BETWEEN` or `<=` when using a `DATE` variable against a `DATETIME` field, is that any time after midnight on the last day will be excluded.

`'2015-02-11 13:07:56.017'`  is greater than `'2015-02-11'`  Rather than casting your field as `DATE` for comparison, it's better for performance to add a day to your variable and change from `<=` to `<`.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Always a race!

Comment: This is the closest correct answer for me. But still have an issue. It doesn't seem to be working inclusively. The DateCreated field is datetime, but the input parameters `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` are date. Could that have something to do with this issue?

Comment: @leo.t Definitely! Since date has no time component, a datetime on the same date for anything after midnight will not be included on the last day of your range, updated.

Comment: It's worth mention that there's a problem if @DateTo has already the max value for a DATETIME(December 31, 9999). DATEADD will return an error - "Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow."

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
WHERE ((DateCreated >= @DateFrom OR @DateFrom IS NULL) AND (DateCreated =< @DateTo OR @DateTo IS NULL))
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this logic defeats the indexing on DateCreated. I discovered this through testing to confirm my losing argument against @AaronBertrand above

Comment: @Matt if you run the same query with the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint you should find that it uses an index on `CreatedDate` - the reason you won't see it used as standard is that (assuming you have run this ad hoc with declared parameters) the query is compiled with in a "one plan fits all" manner. If the plan uses an index seek and a key lookup then when run with both parameters null the performance will be awful, if the plan uses a table scan then when run with both dates not null to return a small number of rows the performance will still be bad, but not as bad.

Comment: @GarethD, assertions confirmed. Awful with nulls, great without. I'm gonna stop trying to be helpful now!

Comment: what about coalesce like in @prowler 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974680/6791342, does that beat indexing?

Answer (score 8):

How About:

```
DateCreated BETWEEN COALESCE(@DateFrom, DateCreated) AND COALESCE(@DateTo, DateCreated)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this `where clause`

```
WHERE  ( DateCreated BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo )
        OR ( @DateFrom IS NULL
             AND @DateTo IS NULL )
        OR ( @DateFrom IS NULL
             AND DateCreated <= @DateTo )
        OR ( @DateTo IS NULL
             AND DateCreated >= @DateFrom )
```

Answer (score 3):

This can simply be done by using ISNULL function.

```
DateCreated BETWEEN ISNULL(@DateFrom,DateCreated) AND ISNULL(@DateTo,DateCreated)
```

Comment: ISNULL is not identical to COALESCE, but in this case, PRowLeR's answer would be better since COALESCE is standardized by SQL: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (DateCreated BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo OR (ISNULL(@DateFrom, '')='' OR ISNULL(@DateTo, '')=''))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.