# SQL - if 2 date params are null show all

Tags: sql-server

I trying to make a query which gives me all records when the two period parameters defining a period are null, and select only the records I need when the parameters are not null.

The 2 parameters are `@PeriodFrom` and `@PeriodeUntil`
I was trying to do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN 
   CASE WHEN @PeriodeFrom IS NULL AND @PeriodeTot IS NULL 
     THEN StartDatum AND CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
     ELSE @PeriodeVan 
  AND @PeriodeTot
```

This one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple boolean logic

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Table
WHERE (@PeriodFrom IS NULL AND @PeriodUntil IS NULL)
OR (StartDate BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodUntil)
```

Comment: I am wondering if it can be that either @ PeriodFrom or @ PeriodUntil can be null

Comment: see my dupe vote suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459783/using-where-clause-with-between-and-null-date-parameters

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev sure, change the `AND` for an `OR`

Answer (score 0):

Handle the null parameters first, then the range.

```
…
where (@PeriodeFrom is null and @PeriodeUntil is null)
   or StartDatum between @PeriodeFrom and @PeriodeUntil
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ISNULL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM [Table]
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN isnull(@PeriodeFrom, StartDate) AND isnull(@PeriodeTot, Startdate)
```